# Truncating post titles in Divi theme using php

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to truncate post titles in my page template.

Here's the code I'm using which isn't working:

```
$titletext = wp_trim_words( get_the_title(), 25, '...' );
$thumbnail = get_thumbnail( $width, $height, $classtext, $titletext, $titletext, false, 'Blogimage' );
```

I've also tried:

```
$titletext = customTitle(30);
```

(having entered the relevant code in functions.php) This has almost worked - it puts the truncated title above the thumbnail, which is fine, except that I don't know how to remove the long title below the thumbnail or change the size of the title above.

The page is: https://thecraftygardeners.co.uk/project/

I'd appreciate some help - I'm a beginner, but I think I'm nearly there...

Comment: I've managed it. I was editing the wrong thing. later on in the template I have changed: <h2 class="entry-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>      to: <h2 class="entry-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php customTitle(20); ?></a></h2>

Answer (score 0):

work with this code:

```
echo mb_substr(get_the_title(), 0, 30);
```

Answer (score 0):

> I don't know how to remove the long title below the thumbnail

There will be `<h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>` in your any one template. Remove that and title will be removed.

> change the size of the title above.

This will be resolved with some lines of CSS.